# Can't De-Compile Windows Phone 8.1 App Installed Assemblies

Tags: .net, windows-phone, decompiling, .net-reflector, dotpeek

I have changed settings to install apps in the SD card in Windows phone 8.1. I then got the installed apps to the PC, and I browsed to the `WPSystem\Apps\{C93F42CB-C64F-45EB-A628-A24891D82A4C}\Install` folder.

There I found several .dll files. I tried to open all of them in Telerik Just Decompiler, and i got the following error:

```
JustDecompile supports only valid CLR assemblies. Not supported files
```

I then download the .Net Reflector, but I got an error there too:

```
File is not a portable executable. DOS header does not contain 'MZ' signature.
```

With DotPeak, I also got the message `not supported`.

Why I am not able to de-compile such apps assembly? Is there any other way?

Answer (score 0):

When you publish an app in the Windows Phone Store, the app is encrypted. So if you want to decompile a xap file from a store application, you have to decrypt it first.